# Any more of this type? $\sum_{j=1}^{k}j\phi^j=\phi^{2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, golden-ratio

Curious equations of phi

$\phi={1+\sqrt5\over 2}$, golden ratio

Here are two examples,

$2\phi^2+1\phi^1=\phi^4$

$4\phi^4+3\phi^3+2\phi^2+1\phi^1=\phi^8$

Comment: This follows from $\varphi^2=\varphi+1$. Note then that $\varphi^3=\varphi^2+\varphi = 2\varphi +1$ and in general $\varphi^n = F_{n}\varphi+F_{n-1}$. You can also use induction directly on your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcr}
  S &=& \phi &+& 2\phi^{2} &+& 3\phi^{3} &+& \ldots &+& k\phi^{k} & \\
  S\phi &=&  & &  \phi^{2} &+& 2\phi^{3} &+& \ldots &+& (k-1)\phi^{k} & +& k\phi^{k+1} \\
 S(1-\phi) &=& \phi &+& \phi^{2} &+& \phi^{3} &+& \ldots &+& \phi^{k} & - & k\phi^{k+1} \\
 &=& \frac{1-\phi^{k+1}}{1-\phi} &-& k\phi^{k+1} \\
S &=& \frac{1-\phi^{k+1}}{(1-\phi)^{2}} &-& \frac{k\phi^{k+1}}{1-\phi}
\end{array}

Note that the mentioned equality holds for $k=2,4$ **only**.